# Podfile.lock: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, cocoapods, podfile

I have scavenged all over the internet trying different solutions to solve this issue however none of the pod install or cocoapods update worked then clean and build worked. This xcode project was created from an exported Unity3d project and the podfile, podfile.lock, and pods folder was already created when I exported the project.

Here's the error screen. There is also a warning which says the debug.xcconfig couldn't be opened because there is no such file however it does exist and the path to it is correct and the configuration tab in the build settings doesn't let me select anything but none:

[image]

Here's the podfile I have:

[image: Here's the podfile I have]

Comment: Delete `podfile.lock` and `pod` folder and run `pod install`.

Comment: Delete pod folder, podfile.lock and running pod install resolved it for me. Thanks to @Shallow Thought's comment